# Dependency property - metadata options without specifying default value

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

```
public double FontSize
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty =
    TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(typeof(OutlineTextBlock),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XXX, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

I don't want to specify `XXX` and there is no override to specify only `AffectsRender`.

If I do like this

```
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
```

then property will take default value from somewhere.

How to specify `AffectsRender` without default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { AffectsRender = true; }
```

By not specifying a default value, the base `PropertyMetadata` does not get flagged as the default value being modified. This ensures when the metadata is merged, the original default value is used but the `AffectsRender` flag is added.

Comment: @Sinatr Don't feel stupid. Afaik there is not a single example on MSDN that shows this way of creating a FrameworkPropertyMetadata instance. The fact that the class has so many (11) constructors will easily let you think that you *have to* use one of them.

Comment: Yeh @Sinatr, I never knew you could do this and I swear I looked into it in the past, we're always learning :)